# Python - determine if a word contains a question mark within it

Tags: python, string, contains

Sometimes character encoding goes wrong, and instead of "It's", you end up with "It?s".
Using Python, can anyone advise on an expression/function which will allow me to determine these instances of a string containing "?", but not at the end of the word?

"Is This It? Nope, that's fine" = False

"It?s This" = True

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off noticing the decoding failure directly?

Comment: @Chris: why do you think encoding errors can only happen in the middle of words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "Is This It? Nope, that's fine"

'?' in s[:-1].replace('? ','')
```

Comment: Looks like it?s been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for regex to me:

```
import re
re.match(r'\w+?\?\w+?',"Is This It? Nope, that's fine") ##Returns a 'match object' which evaluates to True
re.match(r'\w+?\?\w+?',"It?s This") ##Returns None which evaluates to False
```

Then if you want to replace it:

```
re.sub(r'(\w+?)\?(\w+?)',r'\1\2',"It?s This") ##Returns "Its This"
```

The regular expression: '\w+?\?\w+?'
matches one or more word characters: '\w+?'
followed by an actual question mark(escaped): '\?'
followed again by one or more word characters: '\w+?'
this ensures the question mark is in fact in the middle of a word.

As for replacing the question mark,
adding parentheses in your expression like so: '(\w+?)\?(\w+?)'
 creates 2 capture groups which you can then reference as group number one and group number 2 in your desired output like so: '\1\2'
 omitting the question mark.